# I can't use Twitter API v2 with project application

Tags: twitter, bearer-token

I have been very grateful to Twitter API v2. The natural language processing using Twitter data has been very useful for my study. Thank you for everything.

It's been a while since I wanted to get other data, so I ran the data collection code and got the following error

```
Exception: (403, '{"client_id":"19~","detail":"When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.","registration_url":"https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview","title":"Client Forbidden","required_enrollment":"Standard Basic","reason":"client-not-enrolled","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"}')
```

in following code

```
import requests as req

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
params = {'query': ...,
                  'tweet.fields':'created_at',
                  'expansions':'author_id', 
                  'user.fields':'description,created_at,public_metrics',
                  'max_results':'100',
                  'start_time':'2006-03-21T00:00:00Z',
                  'end_time':'2009-01-01T00:00:00Z'}

response = req.request("GET", url, params=params, headers=headers)

if response.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
```

I have a project named ReplyGeneratorbyPGN.[image]

Please give me advice..<(_ _)>

***POSTSCRIPT***

This project is made half a year ago, I regenerated bearer token.
And, this problem solved with [Twitter Academic license](https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/twitter-api/academic-research) .

What is the difference between above and this?

Thank you.

Comment: have you moved the app into a project recently? have you tried regenerating the bearer token and updating it in your configuration? You may be able to find more support on the Twitter developer forum.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. I made the project half year ago. So I regenerated bearer token and updated my code.